# Plugin options page with live preview?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-customizer

I want to build a plugin page with form options and a live preview to auto refresh and display the changes on the frontend. Is it possible to show a live preview of the frontend in the plugin options page?

Similar to WP > Appearance > Customizer but in a plugin options page with custom styled form elements and responsive preview.

What is the best approach you have had success with? Did you use a WP customizer API I do not want to use any framework as this is a very simple project.

Thanks in advance
Vinay

Comment: If you want a preview of the front-end, why not just use the Customiser?

Comment: I need a custom preview window inside the plugin options page.

Comment: But why not add your options to the customiser? Then you don’t need to do anything special.

Comment: As the plugin grow some dynamic data and demos will be added to it which can be too many things to fit in the customizer so I want to create a live preview inside the custom plugin page.

Comment: If it's as simple as you say, @JacobPeattie advice is sound. Otherwise your options are to create a JS/jQuery-powered preview or use an iframe to render the homepage and inject [scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194398/inject-a-javascript-function-into-an-iframe) and [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960406/add-css-to-iframe) into there